Google Sheet IMPORTXML div class struggle
I'm trying to scrape some data with importxml.. and would appreciate a bit of help.
I've managed to get release data and developer via the following..
=IMPORTXML("https://store.steampowered.com/app/1145360/Hades/","//div[@class='release_date']/div[2]")
=IMPORTXML("https://store.steampowered.com/app/1145360/Hades/","//*[@id='developers_list']")
but struggling with the right formula to get Publisher. What could be the right path?
Thanks in advance!
                            <div class="release_date">
                                    <div class="subtitle column">Release Date:</div>
                                    <div class="date">17 Sep, 2020</div>
                                </div>
                            
                                                                                        <div class="dev_row">
                                    <div class="subtitle column">Developer:</div>
                                    <div class="summary column" id="developers_list">
                                        <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/developer/supergiantgames?snr=1_5_9__2000">Supergiant Games</a>                                 </div>
                                </div>
                            
                                                                                                <div class="dev_row">
                                        <div class="subtitle column">Publisher:</div>
                                        <div class="summary column">
                                        <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/publisher/supergiantgames?snr=1_5_9__2000">Supergiant Games</a>                                     </div>
                                    </div>

Link https://store.steampowered.com/app/1145360/Hades/
Tried different variations of this, didn't work though
=IMPORTXML("https://store.steampowered.com/app/1145360/Hades/","//div[@class='dev_row']/div[2]")

Or shorter :
=IMPORTXML("https://store.steampowered.com/app/1145360/Hades/","(//a[contains(@href,'publisher')])[1]")



just:
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://store.steampowered.com/app/1145360/Hades/",
 "//div[@class='dev_row']/div[2]"), 2)


or for sure:
=QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://store.steampowered.com/app/1145360/Hades/",
 "//div[@class='glance_ctn_responsive_left']/div"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 = 'Publisher:'", )


but since you grabbing date and dev too:
=QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://store.steampowered.com/app/1145360/Hades/",
 "//div[@class='glance_ctn_responsive_left']/div"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 matches 'Developer:|Publisher:|Release Date:'", )




That's amazing! You're an absolute star!
